# Disabling zoom meta tag

Tags: html, responsive-design, zooming

What's the comlete version of the zoom disabling viewport meta tag?

I have tried with: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

but it just sets the appropriate scale and doesn't prevent zooming.

I also tried with: `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0,target-densitydpi=device-dpi, user-scalable=no" />`

But it just doesn't work, I can still pinch zoom on my mobile.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It finally worked using that this way:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: Just for clarification purposes, your code includes the closing /, then you say not to use it.  Which is it?

Comment: Isn't it "user-scalable=0" instead of "no" ? I also personally had to add a CSS "touch-action" to the body to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0,target-densitydpi=device-dpi, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The only thing that that meta tag prevents is the horizontal scroll bar, but I can still zoom.

Comment: `target-densitydpi` is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and answer.